# Trying to Convert jQuery ajax to ES6 fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, fetch-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

In an effort to not use jQuery (if `ajax` is all I need it for) I have the following `ajax` call that works like a champ.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Tests/EEG/Portable/Index?handler=Testing",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
  },
  data: JSON.stringify(model),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    alert("Success");
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

I rewrote it in standard javascript using `fetch` as follows:

```
fetch("/Tests/EEG/Portable/Index?handler=Testing", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'XSRF-TOKEN': $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(model)
}).then(checkStatus)
  .then(function (data) {
    alert("second then");
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Failed to load https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/xxx?SAMLRequest=xxx: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:58659' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Which leads me to add the following attribute:

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

Which gives me the following warning (and does not get to my backed method)

> Current.js:78 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/xxx?SAMLRequest=xxx&RelayState=q-9E0I4hwfJLlInurXY-Yu4g with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Which lead me to add the following:

```
'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
```

Which gave me the same warning and still did not get to my server.

Any thoughts on what I am still missing?

***Update***

While looking around the Network tab on Chrome's debugger tools, I noticed the `Copy as fetch` option.  I did this on the working jQuery call and gave me the following JavaScript:

```
fetch("http://localhost:58659/Tests/EEG/Portable/Index?handler=Testing", {
  "credentials": "include",
  "headers": {},
  "referrer": "http://localhost:58659/Tests/EEG/Portable",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": JSON.stringify(model),
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors"
});
```

When I run that `fetch` method I get a `400 Bad request` error.

Comment: Check if your server responds with proper CORS

Comment: Make sure that your API is allowing from the origin `http://localhost:58659`, or from `*` for development only. Also, I'm assuming you're using the full url and not `/Test`?

Comment: @Justinas I assume it does seeing that the jquery version works. Looking at chrome's network tab nothing jumped out as CORS.  I did notice a "copy as fetch" option and added that to an update on my post.

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee I assume it is or the jquey ajax call would not work.  I did not change any code, no, I was not passing the full url to it.  At least until the ***Update*** above.

Comment: You can remove `mode`, `referrer` and `referrerPolicy`. You're also missing those headers, hence why you're getting the bad request.

Comment: Hmm, @WesleyCoetzee I did remove them and get the same `400 (Bad request)` error

Comment: Did you add your headers?

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee yes I did.  I put an answer here too.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad you managed to sort it out :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that thanks to @Wesley Coetzee that got the ball rolling in the right direction.  What took care of it for me was the following code:

```
fetch('/api/Tests/Single', {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'XSRF-TOKEN': $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
  },
  referrer: '/Tests/EEG/Portable',
  referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer-when-downgrade',
  body: JSON.stringify(model),
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors'
});
```

A little back story in case that helps: Everything in the question was based on trying to POST to an ASP.Net Core RazorPage event.  After some realization between this new project we are starting and the extra pain you have to go through (not the above code) to convert a response to an actual entity, we changed to using WebAPI.  The code in this answer is going to a WebAPI controller and no longer a RazorPage method.

Hope it helps someone.